# VScode: Show a prompt when loaded files are modified externally on disk

Tags: visual-studio-code, warnings

Which is the final outcome of the VScode [issue] #14298 (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/14298) ?

Is it: "No, we will **NOT** issue a warning, if an external app modifies a VScode opened file, like **ALL** other editors **do** ? (except Notepad)"

Up to now, I cannot find such a setting...

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23107 Issue seems to be still open.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen a prompt when an open file is changed elsewhere.  What I have seen is a warning when I try to save a file that has been changed elsewhere.  I have seen this: [preventing dirty writes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_preventing-dirty-writes)

> VS Code will show you an error message when you try to save a file
> that cannot be saved because it has changed on disk. VS Code blocks
> saving the file to prevent overwriting changes that have been made
> outside of the editor.
>
> In order to resolve the save conflict, click the Compare action in the
> error message to open a diff editor that will show you the contents of
> the file on disk (to the left) compared to the contents in VS Code (on
> the right):

Until those issues have been resolved I believe that is as close as you are going to get.

Comment: Mark, in Windows, Notepad++, Eclipse IDE, gVim are just among the editors that do exactly what I describe. Even the very old Crimson Editor....